# Can't get python to print out in korean

Tags: python, html, encoding, character-encoding

I am writing a simple web application where I want to use a print out a few korean characters. Although I changed the encoding in the header, the web application, when opened in chrome, prints out gibberish instead of regular Korean characters. I also changed my chrome language settings to display korean as well. Here's my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- encoding: iso-8859-1 -*-


import cgi
import sys
form = cgi.FieldStorage()


print "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1 "
print "Accept-Language: fi, en, ko"
print("Welcome")
print("환영")
print("Tervetuloa")
```

Comment: You can't use ISO-8859-1 for Korean.

Comment: @BrenBarn What should I use? I researched but I couldn't find anything else

Comment: Why don't you use Unicode?

Comment: @洋葱头 I don't know where to add Unicode?

Comment: @comsfollower: I also don't know how to implement it to your application. But does it help if you replace both occurrences of `iso-8859-1` with `utf-8`?

Comment: IT DOES! thank you so much! so i basically changed the encoding comment on top to utf-8 and made charset=utf-8 under that line if anyone is wondering how@洋葱头

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your encoding/charset to a charset that supports all the characters. For example by replacing both occurrences of `iso-8859-1` to `utf-8`. [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) can support Korean characters and basically any writing systems that exist.

Comment: Note that UTF-8 is *not* Unicode, it is simply one charset that can encode *any* Unicode character.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: Thanks for the hint. So should I say a "charset that supports Unicode"? I know there are different charsets, like utf-16, that can also encode Unicode

Comment: I would word it as "a charset that supports all the characters, such as UTF-8".

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [korean package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/korean) :

Example :

```
from korean import Noun
fmt = u'{subj:은} {obj:을} 먹었다.'
print fmt.format(subj=Noun(u'나'), obj=Noun(u'밥'))
print fmt.format(subj=Noun(u'학생'), obj=Noun(u'돈까스'))
```

Output :

```
나은 밥을 먹었다.
학생은 돈까스을 먹었다.
```

Comment: Probably. But how does this relate to generating HTML?